# Adding custom button to Add Article form?

Tags: nodes

I can't seem to get this to work. In my template.php, I have:

```
if($form_id == 'article_node_form'){

    global $user;

    if (in_array('administrator', array_values($user->roles))) {
        //print "here" --> this prints out just fine so this is getting hit
        $form['actions']['save_send_review'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => 'Save & Send for Review',
        '#name' => 'op',
        '#submit' => array('myFunction_form_submit'), 
        '#weight' => 1000
        );
    }
}
```

I can't get the button to appear. What I want to do is:

Have the button appear next to the Save/Preview buttons. Then once clicked, I want it to trigger Workflow to change the status from Creation --> Review automatically (without saving it as Draft first).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In template.php the form is already build.

You have to create a simple module and a [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) to edit your form or add buttons, fields etc.

Comment: Where do I put that code? I'm not that familiar with Drupal...do I call the function "hook_form_alter" in a module that I create?

Comment: Yes, but if you haven't yet create a custom module I suggest you to read here: http://drupal.org/documentation/develop

Comment: I do have a custom module created. Do I just need to add the if-statement in the MyModuleNane_form_alter function?

Comment: Yes, add a if-statement on $form_id and then debug the form to see where you have to add the button